# Grid creation with specific rows and columns

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I have a shapefile for a property boundary and i want to create a grid over this boundary. However I want to be able to specify the number of Rows and Columns, I would also like each individual grid to be able to hold information. I have tried using "Create vector index plugin", and vector grid but it has its problems. Is there any other plugin or application I can use to achieve this. I am using QGIS 2.18.11.

Comment: you should explain why the tool you have tried didn't work for you, so you could get answer suggesting other tool that will work for you or  way to overcome these problem